# How to free memory in python?

Tags: python, memory-management, crash, out-of-memory, infinite-loop

I'm kind of new to python and I need to run a script all day. However, the memory used by the script keeps increasing over time until python crashes... I've tried stuff but nothing works :( Maybe I'm doing something wrong I don't know. Here's what my code looks like :

```
while True:
  try:  

    import functions and modules...
    Init_Variables = ...
    def a bunch of functions...

    def clearall(): #Function to free memory
        all = [var for var in globals() if var[0] != "_" and var != gc]
        for var in all:
            del globals()[var]
        print('Cleared !')
        gc.collect()
        TimeLoop()  #Getting out of "try" here because TimeLoop isn't defined anymore            

    def TimeLoop():

        for i in range (1,101):     
            do stuff...

        # Free memory after 100 iterations #############################
        clearall()

    TimeLoop() # Launches my function when i first start the script

  except Exception as e:
    print(e)
    continue
  break
```

After about 50.000 iterations of "do stuff..." python uses about 2GB of RAM and then crash :(
I spent hours trying to solve this issue but nothing seems to work. Any help would be very much appreciated! :D

Comment: It's very likely that instead of running the same script continuously, it would be better to set up a cronjob to run the script at intervals.

Comment: Like run the script for X mins then kill and restart it ?? Kind of brutal but should work ^^'. however I'd like to find a softer work around haha :)

Comment: No. Run the script, let it finish, then re-run a minute later.

Answer (score 0):

Python frees memory automatically, as soon as no reference to the objects exists any more. You should not try to free memory by yourself. You seem to use recursive calls, which means, each variable in each iteration is kept in memory.

Best practices are, use only local variables, keep your functions short, avoid recursion, don't use cyclic references.

So your script should be as simple as:

```
import functions and modules...
# no global variables
def a bunch of functions...

def main():
    while True:     
        call_function_to_do_stuff()
        # python frees memory automatically after each function call

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main() # Launches my function when i first start the script
```

Comment: It's exactly what it looked like before but I had this memory issue. That's why i made this clearall() function and the while loop.  I make several requests to websites in loop, but the answers I get seems to be stored infinitely. And I don't see how i could make these requests without recursive call :(

Comment: then you should as a question with the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use python64, and dump large data variables to null after x amount of time. I recently managed to get a program to use 8gb ram and python64 worked fine

Comment: I was indeed running in 32 bits, i'll try this out :)